# Separating HTML and JS with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Is there a way in which I can separate my HTML from the data/methods when using VueJS so that I don't have an excessively long file containing both?

I have attempted to just cut what was in my `<script>` section into a new file "methods.js" and imported it using:

```
<script src="methods.js">
```

*note: my methods.js does not contain any `<script>` tags*

Comment: Can't you just use code folding in your editor to make the file easier to deal with?

Comment: I'm wanting to edit on the fly so I can see function names and adjust in the body etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your approach should work, you just need to load the page before loading your script
using `defer`

```
<script src="methods.js" defer></script>
```

..or put the script at the bottom of your body tag.

Comment: Thanks @Tallberg, I  found out that my problem was ending my initial script tag like <script.../> rather than <script></script>